# How to add metadata to nodejs grpc call

Tags: node.js, metadata, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'd like to know how to add metadata to a nodejs grpc function call. I can use channel credentials when making the client with

```
var client = new proto.Document('some.address:8000',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
)
```

Which are send when using `client.Send(doc, callback)`, but the go grpc server looks in the call metadata for identification information which I have to set. I tried using `grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials` with the insecure connection and a `grpc.Metadata` instance but I can't find the right way to do it.

The error I run into is `TypeError: compose's first argument must be a CallCredentials object`. I tried to follow it down but it goes into c code which loses me, I can't see what javascript type I have to give to `comebineChannelCredentials` to achieve what I'm looking for and the docs are a little sparse on how to achieve this.

Comment: What does `doc` refer to?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can pass metadata directly as an optional argument to a method call. So, for example, you could do this:

```
var meta = new grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('key', 'value');
client.send(doc, meta, callback);
```

Answer (score 14):

For sake of completeness I'm going to extend on @murgatroid99 answer.

In order to attach metadata to a message **on the client** you can use:

```
var meta = new grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('key', 'value');
client.send(doc, meta, callback);
```

**On the server** side int your RPC method being called, when you want to grab your data you can use:

```
function(call, callback){ 
   var myVals = call.metadata.get("key"); 
   //My vals will be an array, so if you want to grab a single value:
   var myVal = myVals[0]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I eventually worked it out through introspecting the grpc credentials code and modifying the implementation to expose an inner function. In the `grpc` module in the `node_modules`, file `grpc/src/node/src/credentials.js` add the line

```
exports.CallCredentials = CallCredentials;
```

after `CallCredentials` is imported. Then, in your code, you can write something like

```
var meta = grpc.Metadata();
meta.add('key', 'value');
var extra_creds = grpc.credentials.CallCredentials.createFromPlugin(
  function (url, callback) {
    callback(null, meta);
  }
)
```

Then use `extra_creds` in the client builder

```
var creds = grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials(
  grpc.credentials.createSsl(),
  extra_creds,
)
```

Now you can make your client

```
var client = new proto.Document(
  'some.address:8000',
  creds,
)
```

Comment: That's not necessary. `CallCredentials.createFromPlugin` is already exposed as the more idiomatic `grpc.credentials.createFromMetadataGenerator`. In addition, you can pass metadata directly to calls, without using the credentials interface at all.