# how to coding the server use ssl and Metadata without certificate.

Tags: node.js, metadata, grpc

ssl and Metadata are used in the client.   but how to coding the server?   I do not find the api which use ssl and Metadata without certificate.   like this : 
  [How to add metadata to nodejs grpc call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526077/how-to-add-metadata-to-nodejs-grpc-call)

Comment: const sslCreds = grpc.ServerCredentials.createSsl(
   null,
   [{ private_key: sslServerKey, cert_chain: sslServerCrt }],
   true,
 );

on the server,  the function createSsl must need the second param for  Certificate verify.   How to coding without certificate validation?

Comment: or use the othre  scheme， both not use ssl.   But need to add the Metadata to the channel.  
const metadataUpdater = (serviceUrl, callback) => {  };
const metadataCreds = grpc.credentials.createFromMetadataGenerator(metadataUpdater);
const sslCreds = grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
const combinedCreds = grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials(sslCreds, metadataCreds);
const client = new serviceProto(serviceServerUrl, combinedCreds, clientOptions);

But that's not right!