# How to pass metadata to a gRPC call on nodejs

Tags: node.js, grpc

Once I have I gRPC client (stub) created, say

```
client = new routeguide.RouteGuide(
    localhost:50051,
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure() );
```

How do I pass metadata when calling a method? I know I can use (and I do)   `client.methodName(params);` to call a method, but can I use something like `client.methodName(params, metadata);` ???

I want to pass a JWT token to the server to validate the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add metadata to nodejs grpc call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526077/how-to-add-metadata-to-nodejs-grpc-call)